# Duplicating every frame with ffmeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I plan to do some stop motion animation and would like to shooot in twos - basically shooting at 12fps and duplicating every frame.  I can do this with the camera, but was wondering if there isn't some way to do it with ffmpeg?